# NSObject - saving in loop vs outside loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsobject

Is there any loss in data if I save outside the loop when adding objects vs when I do it inside the loop? Asking since saving outside is much faster.

**Outside Loop:**

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *result in data){
            [manager newManagedCaf];
            for (NSString *name in result){
                if ([name isEqualToString:@"contact"]){
                NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[result valueForKey:name] integerValue]];
                    [[manager cafCards] setValue:num forKey:name];
                }
                else{
                    [[manager cafCards] setValue:[result valueForKey:name] forKey:name];
                }
            }
            [[manager cafCards] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"synced"];
            }
        }
    if(![[manager cafCards].managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Unable to save managed object context.");
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]] message:@"Database not working, try again later or inform IT." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [self getImages:0 con:con withManager:manager];
   }
```

**Inside Loop:**

```
 for(NSMutableDictionary *result in data){
                [manager newManagedCaf];
                for (NSString *name in result){
                    if ([name isEqualToString:@"contact"]){
                    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[result valueForKey:name] integerValue]];
                        [[manager cafCards] setValue:num forKey:name];
                    }
                    else{
                        [[manager cafCards] setValue:[result valueForKey:name] forKey:name];
                    }
                }

                [[manager cafCards] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"synced"];
                if(![[manager cafCards].managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                    NSLog(@"Unable to save managed object context.");
                    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]] message:@"Database not working, try again later or inform IT." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];
                }
            }
```

get the following error when I put error handling outside:

```
[2664:3215894] Unable to save managed object context.
    2017-06-07 14:48:22.644 [2664:3215894] (null), (null)
    2017-06-07 14:48:22.778 [2664:3215894] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no data loss.

It's even the recommended way to commit the data (once) after batch operations.

But you should also move the error handling displaying `Unable to save...` out of the loop after the save line. (Btw: `UIAlertView` is deprecated for a long time).

Comment: I've noticed that the order in which data loads (displayed) is different, when using inside vs outside, is there a reason for this?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. That might be the reason.

Comment: When I move the error handling outside the program crashes (freezes).

Comment: But the error check is directly related to the save line. You don't catch any other errors in the loop. You have to declare `NSError *error;` before the loop.

Comment: Dispatch the code related to `UIAlertView` to the main thread.

Comment: get the same errors except the auto layout engine error. (Program still freezes)

Comment: Actuallly `(null), (null)` means there is no error.

Comment: Instead checking if it saves and if error is present, I did it on a separate line